# How do I search for data from the ison and trigger new functions depending on the select key result?

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda, triggers, endpoint

For example. I'm sending to my rest (with the database - mongoo/dynamodb)

```
such a json:
{
  "item" : "milk",
  "price": "123",
  "other: "other",
}
```

And now, depending on the outcome value for key "item" i want to trigger the right function - return the right result

How can I run a function that will search (filter) in the second database/json result and return it ? So I have a product in the second database/json called **milk** and I would like to take from it for example the **manufacturer**